# Converting binary encoding to classes multilabel python

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning

I have data like this in dataframe

| Text | Label1 | Label2 | label3 | label4 | Labels |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hello my name is john | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |  |

and I want to fill the labels column based on the ones and zeros to be like this

| Text | Label1 | Label2 | label3 | label4 | Labels |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hello my name is john | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | ['Label1','Label3'] |

How can I do in python?

Comment: The values are ready there is no formula to choose them

Comment: I was thinking ['Label1', 'Label**2**'] was a typo that should be ['Label1', 'Label**3**'], can you confirm or not?

Comment: Yes sorry it was a typo .. edited. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is an untested suggestion from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30566899/4475468). Try gathering the appropriate column labels then using DataFrame.apply on a suitable function:

```py
test_cols = [c for c in df.columns if c[:5].lower() == 'label']
test_cols.remove('Labels')

def aggLabels(aSeries):
    return [lab for lab in test_cols if aSeries[lab]==1]

df['Labels'] = df.apply(aggLabels, axis=1)
```

As I say this is untested; there may be code tweaks required.